# Explanation of column in ssrs report

Tags: ssrs-2008, tooltip

Is there any way to have information hidden on a report that only appear when you hover the cursor over the column / row ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Tooltips** to create a **Hover Over** but you would have to create them for the cells - you can't do it for an entire row or column.

You could select multiple cells in a row or column and update the tooltip expression at the same time. It will be like a tooltip for the row or column but actually you're updating the property of all the individual cells.

[image: ToolTip]